# Non-parseable POM SpringBoot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

> My Project was working fine then I needed to add a dependency, After
> adding the dependency I was not able to Import class file from newly
> added dependency so I Updated the project Maven, Update Project after
> that I started facing this issue.

#### I have tried these options.

```
1: Deleted .m2 directory
2: Deleted workspace
3: Re-Installed Maven
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mcs.pmay</groupId>
<artifactId>pmay</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>pmay</name>
<description>PMAY Project - Housing for All</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.mkammerer</groupId>
        <artifactId>argon2-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId> 
        <optional>true</optional> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>javaxt</groupId>
     <artifactId>javaxt-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.1</version>
   </dependency>
            
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>javaxt.com</id>
     <url>http://www.javaxt.com/maven</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solved the issue by these steps.

1. Updated SpringBoot version 1.4.3.RELEASE to 1.5.14.RELEASE.
2. Closed the eclipse.
3. Deleted .m2 directory.
4. Open project in eclipse.
5. Maven Update Project.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you added javaxt as repository, but it is giving you the wrong content for the spring-boot-starter-parent.

just click on http://www.javaxt.com/maven/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.4.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.4.3.RELEASE.pom and you'll see the content. It should be a pom, but it is not.

I'd suggest removing or replacing the repository.

Comment: As Robert already mentioned ...remote the repository definition cause the whole spring boot project is available from central...

Comment: Even if I removed javaxt dependency still getting same error but if I update Spring Boot version to 1.5.14.RELEASE then this issue is fixed but getting new error Description Resource Path Location Type
Archive for required library: '/Users/chandrakumar/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest/1.5.14.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar' in project 'pmay' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file pmay  Build path Build Path Problem

Comment: I said remove the javaxt *repository*, not dependency. To me it looks like this repo is causing a lot of issues, providing wrong artifacts and poms.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is well formed and there are no issues with the repositories, try using the previous version of Spring boot starter. Example -

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

And do a maven update, it should work.